# ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(72,69): error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: angular

working on angular 6 trying to call a method of service.ts file from app.component.ts

```
play(){
    this.uploadService.playClientRecord(this.result1).subscribe(data:any=>{
        console.log('method called');
    });
    console.log('started Playing records');
    this.isPlayed=true;
}
```

**service.ts**

```
playClientRecord(model: any){
    console.log('MOD'+model);
    const options = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};
    this.http.post('http://10.71.9.178:8080/replayservice/uploadFile', model, options).map(response=>response.json()).subscribe(
        event => console.info(JSON.stringify(t))
    );
}
```

Getting an error while compiling code

> Date: 2018-09-07T07:12:53.215Z - Hash: a4e278d9bdebc1d005c6 - Time:
>   302ms 5 unchanged chunks i ?wdm?: Compiled successfully. i ?wdm?:
>   Compiling...  10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ._code
>   base\client\src\app\app.module.tsERROR in
>   src/app/app.component.ts(72,69): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> Date: 2018-09-07T07:14:57.482Z - Hash: 192e0278be7a3932111d - Time:
>   177ms 4 unchanged chunks chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 18.1
>   kB [initial] [rendered] i ?wdm?: Compiled successfully.

Comment: You need a return in your service method and brackets around `data: any` in your component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

> Instead of **data:any** use **(data:any)**
>   component:

```
import { UploadFileService } from './upload-file.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [UploadFileService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private uploadService: UploadFileService) { }

  play() {
    this.uploadService.playClientRecord(this.result1).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    console.log('started Playing records');
  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class UploadFileService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  playClientRecord(model: any): Observable<any> {
    const options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
    return this.http.post('http://10.71.9.178:8080/replayservice/establishsession ', model, options);
  }
}
```

in app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UploadFileService } from './upload-file.service'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [UploadFileService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(72,24): error TS2339: Property 'playClientRecord' does not exist on type 'UploadFileService'.
getting this

Comment: update service as i have given

Comment: It will work fine check edits and let me know.

Comment: getting same error ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(72,24): error TS2339: Property 'playClientRecord' does not exist on type 'UploadFileService'.

Comment: please share complete code.

Comment: component an d service??

Comment: updated code:     play(){
  
    this.uploadService.playClientRecord(this.result1).subscribe((data:any)=>{
  
  });
    console.log('started Playing records');
    this.isPlayed=true;
   }

Comment: playClientRecord(model: any): Observable<any> {
  
    const options = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};
    this.http.post('http://10.71.9.178:8080/replayservice/establishsession', model, options).map(response=>response.json())
}

Comment: have you created constructor.

Comment: put you code here i will check it https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: i have added code

Comment: https://angular-aqaacd.stackblitz.io

Comment: please  share editable code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmuc3l

Comment: have you added U[loadFileService in app.module.ts

Comment: no UploadFileService not added in app.module.ts

Comment: Check edits and works fine

Comment: Check Complete edits and still problem ping back?

Comment: not resolving facing same issue

Comment: Working Fine ---> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sl685s